# accessing $window and $logProvider in angular

Tags: angularjs

When I am trying this (CoffeeScript)

```
.config ['$logProvider', '$window', ($logProvider, $window) ->
   //...do something with parameters...
   ]
```

I get "$window not defined", and whe I try run block

```
.run ['$logProvider', '$window', ($logProvider, $window) ->
   //...do something with parameters...
   ]
```

I get "Unknown provider: $logProviderProvider <- $logProvider"

I there any way I can use both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providers are only scoped at config time, then their provided service is available:

```
.config ['$logProvider', ($logProvider) ->
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
]

.run ['$log', '$window', ($log, $window) ->
    $log.debug('hello logger!');
]
```

Note that `$window` is not a provider thus can't be configured.

Your answer is: `.config` handles pure module configuration. Once done, factories are ready so you can use everything you need. In your case, you actually need `$log` and `$window`.

Comment: I need to condifure $logProvider based on $window.  I wonder if it's doable without my current workaround with `window` in lieu of `$window`.

Comment: `$window` is a *service*, so you can't use it in a `config` block, which means that you can't use it to configure a provider. You will have to directly use `window`, which doesn't seem that bad to me considering we're in a configration block. See the doc for more details: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window